# Compare NSDictionaries containing NSStrings

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa, foundation

I have two `NSDictionaries` containing `NSStrings`. To compare this two dictionaries I use `isEqualToDictionary:` method. The documentation on `isEqualToDictionary:`says

"Two dictionaries have equal contents if they each hold the same number of entries and, for a given key, the corresponding value objects in each dictionary satisfy the isEqual: test."

So, my strings are compared by `isEqual:` method.

The question is:
How does `isEqual:` work for the `NSString`?

Does it use `isEqual:` from `NSObject`?
I've read that `isEqual` from `NSObject` just compares addresses, using `==`.
To prove or disprove this idea I wrote a sample:

```
NSString *str1 = @"sampleString";
NSString *str2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"sampleString"];
BOOL result = [str1 isEqual:str2];
```

The `result` is `YES`, the addresses of `str1` and `str2` are different though.

So, either it does not use `isEqual:` from `NSObject` (what than?), or `NSObject`'s `isEqual:` does something more complicated then just checking equality of addresses.

Does anybody know how does it really work?

Comment: Why can't you use isEqualToString method? too easy?

Comment: @SamBudda It's not me, it's NSDictionary uses isEqual: comparing its elements.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`NSString` overrides `isEqual:` to properly compare strings, so you're perfectly fine to comparing dictionaries this way.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to make sure of it? Headers and documentation for NSString says nothing.

Comment: I found it, this fact is mentioned in "Objective-c Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide".

Comment: @Anastasia Also, it's very indirectly mentioned in the docs under [`isEqualToString:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/isEqualToString:) which says it's the same as `isEqual:` when both are strings, but faster.

Answer (score 5):

isEqualToDictionary compares every object with isEqual.

In my case it doesn't work with NSString object in my dictionary. So i made a very simple workaround. I compare the description of both dictionaries. This works with dictionaries containing NSString and NSNumber and whit all objects containing a description method.

```
[[myDict1 description] isEqualToString:[myDict2 description]]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Compare literal descriptions** of dictionaries. I'm using it in unit tests.

```
NSString *a = dictionary.description;
NSString *b = assertation.description;
BOOL test = [a isEqualToString:b];
```

Comment: `NSDictionary` is not ordered I think.